# Why aren't the ARObjects being drawn when the AndARActivity is called from another activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, andar

When I start the `AndARActivity` as the main activity, the camera is activated and the `ARObjects` will be drawn correctly.  If I call the `AndARActivity` from another, normal `Activity`, the camera is activated, but the `ARObjects` will not be drawn.

Why aren't the `ARObjects` being drawn?

**BreakoutARActivity.java**

```
public class BreakoutARActivity extends AndARActivity
```

**main.xml**

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/play"
        style="@style/dashButtonStyle"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/play"
        android:onClick="play"
        android:src="@drawable/play" />
```

**manifest.xml**

```
     <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".BreakoutLauncherActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".BreakoutARActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
         <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="ch.bfh.ti.breakoutar.activity.BreakoutARActivity" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**BreakoutLauncherActivity.java**

```
public class BreakoutLauncherActivity extends Activity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

public void play(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, BreakoutARActivity.class);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```